# Set Table Cell Value and Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a web form that allows users to enter details for creating a shipping consignment for 1 more more items. They enter the address from/to fields and then there's a table where they can enter 1 or more rows for items to be included on the shipment.

One of the table columns is for the Product ID, which is a value that is returned from a database query performed when entering a code in another table cell. We don't want users entering/editing this so we're including this as a hidden input but we would also like to display this to the user.

Here's what one of the table rows looks like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="shipmentItems" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">Product Code</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="10%">Qty</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="55%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="5%"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control productID" name="productID[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control productCode" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Product Code" name="productCode[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Qty" name="qty[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="description"></td>
      <td class="text-center deleteRow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
    </tr>
```

When the user enters the Product Code value an AJAX request is performed to do the database query and I then use the following to update the other cells:

```
$this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.productID').html(productID);
$this.closest('tr').find('.form-control.productID').val(productID);
$this.closest('tr').children('.description').html(description);
```

The last two are updating correctly (hidden productID input value) and the description, but the value for the Product ID cell is remaining empty. I'm assuming I can have a hidden input value and a non input value for the same table cell at the same time and update both separately?

Comment: how did you verify that the value is remaining empty ? can you test once by not making the cell empty ?

Comment: also, what's wrong with just using: `$this.closest('tr').children('.productID').html(productID);` notice `form-control` is not used to find the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.productID').html(productID);
```

This attempts to set the HTML of your inputs (all of them in the row).  But `text` and `hidden` inputs *have* no HTML, only a `value`.

I think you're actually trying to set the HTML of the table cells, which you can do like so:

```
$this.closest('tr').find('td').html(productID);
```

Note that (like your existing code) this will match every `td`; judging by the table headers you really only want to match the first one:

```
$this.closest('tr').find('td').first().html(productID);
```

Note 2 that this is a bit fragile, and will break if your table structure changes.  It would be safer to add a class to the cell you want to update, eg `<td class='product_id'>`, and target that with your selector.

```js
$('.productCode').on('keyup', function() {
    let productID = 42;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().html(productID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Type a letter in product code field to simulate your AJAX call:</p>


<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control productID" name="productID[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control productCode" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Product Code" name="productCode[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Qty" name="qty[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="description"></td>
    </tr>
```